# HttpClient.SendRequestAsync triggering ArgumentException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I've been trying to upload a photo to a server whenever the user wants to change it's avatar.

Everything is fine from the photo taken, getting the photo into a `IRandomAccessStream` and into a `HttpMultipartFormDataContent` but when I try to send the request an `ArgumentException` is thrown.

For what I've seen on debug, nothing seems be wrong, but the exception is thrown anyway.

Here is the code:

```
public static async Task<WebResult> UploadImage( WebHost webHost, Object webPath, String webQuery, IRandomAccessStream imageStream ) {

    /* ... */

    HttpClient
        httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();

    HttpMultipartFormDataContent
        httpMultipartContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

    HttpStreamContent
        httpStreamContent = new HttpStreamContent( imageStream );

    httpStreamContent.Headers.Add( "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream" );
    httpMultipartContent.Add( httpStreamContent, "userAvatar", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString( "yyyyMMddhhmmssffff" ) + ".png" );

    try {
        HttpRequestMessage
            httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Post, new Uri( /* ... */ ) );

        Dictionary<String, String>
            webCredentialsDictionary = WebServerAuthenticationCredentials( /* ... */ ) as Dictionary<String, String>;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> credentialEntry in webCredentialsDictionary) {
            httpRequest.Headers.Add( credentialEntry );
        }

        httpRequest.Content = httpMultipartContent;

        /* The ArgumentException is thrown here. */
        HttpResponseMessage
            httpResponse = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync( httpRequest );

        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return new WebResult( true, true, null );
    } catch (ArgumentException exception) {

    } catch (Exception exception) {

    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Is there anything that I should setting up before executing the request?

Also, here's the stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at WindowsPhoneFramework.WebController.<UploadImage>d__28.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What values are you passing into `httpRequest.Headers.Add()`? And how are you creating the stream?

Comment: The values that are added to the `httpRequest.Headers` are crendentials necessary to perform requests on that server. The stream comes from a `MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToMemoryAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I tried to send a `MemoryStream` converted to `IInputStream`

```
request.Content = new HttpStreamContent(ms.AsInputStream());
```

and the solution was setting the Position of the stream to the beginning before setting it as a content.